# How to fix NPM warnings

Tags: npm

When i did some git-clone i did get these warnings somebody who knows how to fix these warnings below?

```
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-flowtype@3.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

audited 918322 packages in 74.903s

45 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `--suppess-warnings` or `--loglevel=error` but it would be better to fix them instead.